# How can I keep the Generics type in the C# code output from Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I'd like to use an Array with type in C#.

I tried building the following code in Haxe 4.0.5, but hoges is an `Array<object>` in C#. (I wanted `Array<Hoge>`)

```
class ArrayTest
{
    public var hoges: Array<Hoge>;
}

class Hoge
{
    public var x: Int;
    public var y: Int;
    public var z: Int;
}
```

I found the following post on github and understand that this behavior is a spec to make the code faster.
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/5434#issuecomment-230581990.

However, I'm hoping it comes with a type because I want to use this code as an interface.
Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is primarily for purposes of interfacing with external code, using a C#-specific collection can be more fitting:

```
import cs.system.collections.generic.List_1;

class Main {
    public static var hoges:List_1<Hoge> = new List_1();
    static function main() {
        hoges.Add(new Hoge());
        trace(hoges[0]);
    }
}
class Hoge {
    public var x: Int;
    public var y: Int;
    public var z: Int;
    public function new() {}
}
```

which produces

```cs
public static global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::Hoge> hoges;
```

as you would expect.

Abstracts can be used to switch implementations depending on the target platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I was trying to generate C# and javascript code from the same source code.

Is there another smart way to do this instead of controlling with the Compiler Flag?

Comment: You can have `#if cs` / `#if js` / etc. to pick implementations based on target platform - each platform automatically declares one or more compiler flags; when using libraries, #if <lib_name> can also be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NativeArray

```
typedef Hoges = cs.NativeArray<Hoge>;
class ArrayTest { public var hoges: Hoges; }
```

generating

```
public global::Hoge[] hoges;
```